# Recording gas usage at a specific point in execution

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, gas, gas-limit

I apologize if it has already been asked here, but i'm currently building a limit orders contract and i'm trying to do something like that.

```
function fullfillMaxOrders() public {
while(gasConsumed <= gasLimit) {
    // do my stuff (which is running through a list of orders to process, each individual order may widely vary in gas usage (different tokens to transfer, different contracts to interact with...)
    //record gas consumed up to this point and store it in gasConsumed
}
// rest of the function
```

}
do you know how one could do that? I'm talking about the recording the gas consumed up to this point of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is called

```
gasleft() returns (uint256): remaining gas
```

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/units-and-global-variables.html

Comment: Thx, exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Just curious, how would metamask estimate the gas cost of such a function? Since its cost depends on the number of iterations of the loop, which itself depends on the gas limit. (Note that i wont actually use it, the gas limit will be hardcoded. But still, just curious)

Comment: there is a function in the RPC called `eth_estimateGas` , check it out

Comment: `eth_estimateGas` gets pretty wrong many times